# session id change and attributes copying after login

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, servlets

My application use java servlets,jsp and tomcat 6. I like to implement session id change and want to copy the old session attributes to the new one after login. We started using a little bit of spring in this. 
Which is the best way to add this feature to a 10 year old application like this.

Comment: Why do you need to change the session id?

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: chanching session id after login prevents session hijacking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use Spring Security, the framework should change the session id after login by default.

@see [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-new-session-on-authentication):

> Why does the session Id change when I authenticate through Spring Security?
>
> With the default configuration, Spring Security invalidates the existing session when the user authenticates and creates a new one, transferring the session data to it. The intention is to change the session identifier to prevent “session-fixation” attacks. You can find more about this online and in the reference manual

---

If you do not use Spring (Security) you have to do it by your own. A bit in this way:

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
...
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Map<String,Object> values = session.GetAll(); //This line is psydo code
    //Use getValueNames() and a loop with getValue(String name);

    // Kill the current session
   session.invalidate();

   HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
   newSession.putAllValues(values); //This line is psydo code
...
```

Comment: When I call session.invalidate() is throws an exception.java.lang.IllegalStateException: getLastAccessedTime: Session already invalidated

Comment: To my understanding: the doc said you do not need to do anything. Have you checked that the session id does not change automatically, before trying to implement your own logic?

Comment: sorry. the context is different. It is not about spring security

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to add session attribute just after login? Where should I put the adding attribute part? I am using Spring Security Just in case

Comment: @Dhruv Singhal: you could implement a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to get access to the Http Session after successfull login (do not forget to invoke the "original" `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Or you hook up at the `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` or `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` and try to get access to the http request via `RequestContextHolder` _(I never used `RequestContextHolder` before, so I do not know how to get it running)_

Comment: Thanks a ton, somehow I also got the link for tutorials explaining the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
    session=request.getSession(true);
    Enumeration keys = session.getAttributeNames();     
    HashMap<String,Object> hm=new HashMap<String,Object>();  
    while (keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
      String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
      hm.put(key,session.getValue(key));
      session.removeAttribute(key);      
    }
    session.invalidate();
    session=request.getSession(true);
    for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet())
    {
      session.setAttribute((String)m.getKey(),m.getValue());  
      hm.remove(m);
    }
```

Comment: Some more explanation helps folks to understand clearly

Answer (score 1):

```
private void regenrateSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
  
  HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession();
  
  Enumeration attrNames = oldSession.getAttributeNames();
  Properties props = new Properties();
  
  while (attrNames != null && attrNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
   props.put(key, oldSession.getAttribute(key));
  }
  
  oldSession.invalidate();
  HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
  attrNames = props.keys();
  
  while (attrNames != null && attrNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
   newSession.setAttribute(key, props.get(key));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", null);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addProperty(cookie);
```